# Flutter Doctor is not detecting flutter and dart plugin in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I updated Android studio to 4.1.0, after updating I am getting the issue of missing flutter and dart plugin but both is already added. I removed the flutter and dart plugin and again added but still same issue persist. I am able to run or debug my flutter application. I don't know why flutter doctor is giving such issue.
I have executed

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\"
```

also in terminal but not resolved.My flutter SDK path is `C:\flutter` and Dart SDK path is `C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk`
If any one have solution, Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Thank You

Comment: I had same issue before, starting simple flutter app from android studio solved my problem

Comment: This won't be problem,try to run the app,i have same problem but i can run the app without any problem,i have same issue i think most of them have same issue after android studio 4.1 @FAIZ ANWAR

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. I wasn't before the big Android Studio update. Very annoying.

Comment: It would be better if you inserted flutter doctor output as text instead of the image, so that others can more easily find your question